# Exclude root directories using os.walk

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm trying to list all the files my laptop but I want to exclude some root directories.

For example:
I have the follwoing files:

```
 /Users/teste/demo/file.csv
 /Users/teste/demo3/file.csv
 /Users/project/file.csv
```

What I want is to exclude all the files from `/Users/teste/`. For that I have this code:

```
import os
exclude = ['/Users/teste/',]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("\\", topdown=False):
    if root not in exclude:
        for name in files:
            print(name)
```

However, my code is printing the files from directory demo and demo3 because the root include the demo part. If I print the root I will get:

```
/Users/teste/demo 
/Users/teste/demo3 
/Users/project/
```

And I want to include only the `/Users/project/file.csv` file

How can I filter using the parent root?

Comment: what do you get in `print( root )` ? Maybe it is different then you expect.

Comment: I get what I said on the question: 
/Users/teste/demo 
/Users/teste/demo3 
/Users/project/

Comment: you can always test `root.startswith("/Users/teste/")`

Comment: but with that I loose the list function If I need to filter more directories

Comment: then create function which uses for-loop to test all elements on list

Comment: @furas you can make a list of unwanted directories and iterate over it to check if the current file from os.walk does not start with the current element in the list

Comment: BTW: I forgot that you can use tuple (not list) `root.startswith( ("/Users/teste/", "/other/folder") )`

Comment: This is easier to do when `topdown=True`, is there any reason to make it false? With `True`, you can block subdirectory scanning completely, with `False` all files in the file system will be enumerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `startswith` with `tuple` (not list)

```
if not root.startswith( ('/Users/teste/', '/other/folder') ):
```

---

```
import os

exclude = ['/Users/teste/',]

exclude = tuple(exclude)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("\\", topdown=False):
    if not root.startswith(exclude):
        for name in files:
            print(name)
```

---

**BTW:**

If you want to use function which can't get list or tuple then you can use `any()` with list comprehension to check all elements on list

For example for `startswith()`

```
if not any(root.startswith(x) for x in exclude):
```

or for `regex` (which can be useful to create more complex element in `exclude`)

```
if not any(re.findall(x, root) for x in exclude):
```